# How to full uninstall SharePoint 2010

Tags: development, gac

I wanted a clean install of SharePoint 2010 so I recently uninstalled it as well as deleted all the content databases from Central Admin and SQL Management server. I then re-installed SharePoint 2010 and to my surprise and dismay, I noticed all the features and feature ID's and GUIDs were still there.

The whole reason I did this uninstallation process is because I have been developing on my SharePoint site for months and it is clogged up with artifacts and remnants of various solutions and features and I wanted a clean slate.

Does anyone know what needs to be done to completely remove all traces of anything SharePoint 2010 related? Does the GAC need to be cleaned out? Does each feature and solution need to be deactivated and removed? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After you do all of the above, make sure you also completely remove the SharePoint Config database as well as delete your 14 hive.

Comment: If you are virtual, you may want to keep a clean OS as your base going forward and utilize difference disk or linked clones.  This makes it easy to 'revert' back to a clean state.

Comment: Sadly my computer doesn't support 64 bit virtualization so this isn't an option but it is something I have brought up to the System Admins and hopefully in the future we will be working on virtual machines.

Comment: By SharePoint Config database, you are talking about the one in SQL Server named "SharePoint_Config"? Here is a screenshot of my SQL databases, I removed every one of them except for "System Databases" and "Database Snapshots". http://imgur.com/FjpUh

Comment: Yup, that is what Dave is referring to.  If you don't need the configs / content you can just delete them all.  As a tip, you can see which Databases belong to SharePoint and are active (i.e. being used) via the Central Admin Backup UI.